# CSS - Side by Side div equal width, but at tablet size take up full screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am creating a form and I have 2 `divs` that are side by side.  Here is my current html:

```
  <div class="form-row-fluid">
    <div class="form-field">
      <label>First name</label>
      <input class="input-thick">
      </input>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
      <label>Middle name</label>
      <input class="input-thick">
      </input>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And css:

```
.form-row-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline;
}
.form-field {
  width: 46%;
}
```

I have looked at another answer that said to use a `display: table`, but I can't get that to be as responsive as I need.  When I get to tablet size, I want each `form-field` to go to `width: 100%`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AlienArrays He said at "tablet size", that would make it 100% *all* the time.

Comment: @jhamm Just food for thought - There is no set "tablet size", iPads for example are 1024x768, which may have a width of 768 just depending on which orientation they're holding it.

Comment: When I said tablet size I meant under 768.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use floats (and media queries of course).

```
.form-row-fluid {
    width: 100%;    
}

.form-field {
    width: 46%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    .form-field { width: 100%; }
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zz29T/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
  .input-thick { width: 100%; }
}
```

You should use media queries if you want responsive CSS.